# Get a node/content picker in a custom grid editor (Umbraco 7)

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Using the Umbraco 7 grid editor, I need to be able to select a content item with the Umbraco node picker within a custom grid editor, but I'm having trouble in achieving this. There is a media picker available, but I can't figure out how this could be changed to pick any content node.

I have also tried to use the settings/styles option in the grid editor, which I can get a node picker within, but then I am unable to get this information through to the custom grid editor views. Could anyone point me in the right direction here? Surely being able to provide a link to a content page is a relatively common thing to do from the U7 grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a custom `Content and Link picker` grid editors for Umbraco v8. It is available on GitHub

https://github.com/mausba/umbraco-v8-content-and-link-pickers-as-grid-editors

It is pretty simple actually! You create 4 files inside `/AppPlugins/YourPackage` folder - for content picker it would be something like this:

**package.manifest** - this file holds all the information about the editor

```
{
  "gridEditors": [
    {
      "name": "Content Picker",
      "alias": "customcontentpicker",
      "view": "/app_plugins/custom.grideditor.contentpicker/contentpicker.html",
      "icon": "icon-link"
    }
  ],
  "javascript": [
    "~/app_plugins/custom.grideditor.contentpicker/contentpicker.controllers.js"
  ]
}
```

**contentPicker.html** - this file is used to render the content inside the umbraco backoffice

```
<div ng-controller="custom.propertyeditors.grid.contentpickereditorcontroller">

    <div class="umb-editor-placeholde" ng-click="setContentId()">
        <i class="icon icon-settings-alt"></i>
        <div ng-id="!control.$inserted" class="help-text">Click to insert Page</div>

        <div ng-if="control.value" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <p>
                Node ID: {{id}}
                <br />
                Node Name: {{name}}
                <br />
                udi: {{udi}}
            </p>
            {{control.value}}
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**contentpicker.controllers.js** - This file is used to wire up a controller to this view

```
angular.module("umbraco")
    .controller("custom.propertyeditors.grid.contentpickereditorcontroller",
        function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, editorService) {

            $scope.setContentId = function () {

                const contentPicker = {
                    submit: function (model) {
                        var selection = model.selection[0];
                        $scope.control.value = {
                            id: selection.id,
                            name: selection.name,
                            udi: selection.udi
                        };
                        $scope.setPreview();
                        editorService.close();
                    },
                    close: function () {
                        editorService.close();
                    }
                };
                editorService.contentPicker(contentPicker);
            };

            $scope.setPreview = function () {

                if (!$scope.control.value.id) return;

                $scope.id = $scope.control.value.id;
                $scope.name = $scope.control.value.name;
                $scope.udi = $scope.control.value.udi;
            };

            $timeout(function () {
                if ($scope.control.$initializing) {
                    $scope.setContentId();
                } else {
                    $scope.setPreview();
                }
            }, 200);

        });
```

**contentpicker.cshtml** - this is the template that is used on the frontend to render the grid content

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<dynamic>

@{
    if (Model.value == null) { return; }
}

@Model.value.name
@Model.value.id
@Model.value.udi
```

If you then recycle the app pool and if you did the above steps correctly you should see something like this:

[image: Content Picker as a new grid editor]

[image: Content Picker grid editor]

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of a custom node picker as a new grid editor in Umbraco 7 on the our.umbraco.org forum [here](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/59563-Tutorial-on-creating-custom-grid-editors?p=0), with a code example.

Comment: It's a bad practice to put a link to an external site without a minimum explanation, because the link can die rendering the answer useless. Please, improve your answer to help the community, with an excerpt or a summary of the interesting linked page. That would be useful to find the information if the link dies. Thank you!